# How does one use monadic properties in SmallCheck?

Tags: testing, haskell, monads, smallcheck

I would like to write a SmallCheck property that uses IO, but I can't figure out how I am supposed to do it.  Specifically, the goal is to write a property that is an instance of `Testable IO Bool` so that I can feed it into `smallCheck` (or `testProperty` in `test-framework`).  Unfortunately, the best I can come up with is the following:

```
smallCheck 5 (\(x :: Int) → return True :: IO Bool)
```

This doesn't work because it is an instance of `Testable IO (IO Bool)` rather than `Testable IO Bool`, but I can't figure out how to rewrite it so that it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the `monadic` combinator. It takes an arbitrary monad `m` and wraps it into a `Property` that is an instance of `Testable`.

```
smallCheck 5  $ \(x :: Int) -> monadic $ (return True :: IO Bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is a function that does exactly what I wanted:

```
monadic :: Testable m a => m a -> Property m
```

You use it like so:

```
smallCheck 5 $ \(x :: Int) → monadic (putStrLn (show x) >> return True)
```

Specifically, note how `monadic` needs to be nested *after* the function argument.